# Intercept image upload (for Facebook) using Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I have Chrome extensions that intercepts to submission of new Facebook posts to check the content. For the text, this is pretty straightforward. If I press the "Post" button, for the resulting event `e`, I call

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

get the text of the post and send it to my server for the analysis.

But how can I do this now for images. When I click the "Photo/Video" button, a file selector dialog opens. Once I select an image, it seems that it gets immediately uploaded, processed, and a thumbnail version is displayed.

I wouldn't even mind right now that the images gets already uploaded to Facebook, but I would still like to somehow fetch the image to send to my server for analysis. I already got it working for Twitter, but there the original images are accessible via local URLs, i.e., `blob:https://...`. I was hoping that approach would work for Facebook as well.

The `alt` attribute if the `img` element for the thumbnail seems to contain the file name but not the full path. So I don't think that's much useful. The "Photo/Video" button is a `input` element; maybe I can add some listeners to it?

Comment: Maybe you could hide the original upload input, add your own in its place, when yours is used, do your stuff with it, then pass the image off to the original input

Comment: @WesleySmith Hm, yeah, I can see this working. But that it also seems to require a lot of effort. Ideally, I would need to completely mimic the original look-&-feel of the upload process. Right now I'm looking for a proof-of-concept solution. The Facebook website is also a highly dynamic site. Note sure how I could pass analyzed images to the original upload process.

Comment: @Christian did you ever find a solution for this?